# Rails helper - how to return an array of images to the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to build a helper in rails that returns an array of image_tags for the view.

```
def thumbnails
 arry = [
 image_tag('image1.png')
 image_tag('image2.png')
 image_tag('image3.png')
 ]
 return arry[0]
end
```

I can get as far as returning a single image, like in the example above, but I'm not sure how to return them all...anything I try to do to iterate over the array causes the view to render the html code for an image rather than the image itself.

Help appreciated as always.

Comment: Show more code, including what you're trying to do with them in the view.

Comment: You'll definitely want to return the whole array; can you also post your view code? I do seem to recall running into this issue once or twice.

Comment: In my example, the view code would literally be <%= thumbnails %>, which would simply display image1.png.  What I am asking is can I keep the view code as <%= thumbnails %> and render ALL of the images in the array somehow i.e. the looping happens before I return the array rather than in the view

Answer (score 6):

If I understand the question correctly, if you want to join all of them together you could do something like this:

```
def thumbnails
  raw [
       image_tag('image1.png'),
       image_tag('image2.png'),
       image_tag('image3.png')
      ].join()
end
```

This will result in a string like:

```
<img src='/images/image1.png' /><img src='/images/image12.png' /><img src='/images/image3.png' />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do a partial _thumbnail and pass it an object containing an array of AR objects or an array of filenames. In the partial:

```
<%= image_tag(thumbnail)  #or image_tag(thumbnail.file_name) if AR object %>
```

And in the referencing view:

```
<%= render(:partial => "thumbnail", :collection => @thumbnails) %>
```

Supplying a :collection to the partial causes Rails to automatically repeat it for each object - using an object name that matches the partial name for each instance. The @thumbnails being passed from the referencing view is the array set up in your controller:

```
@thumbnails = ["image1.png","image2.png","image3.png","image4.png"]
```

or

```
@thumbnails = Thumbnails.find(:all)
```

etc.

HTH